# I am looking for dynamic insert statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am looking for dynamic insert statement in oracle like below for each partition (which need trim for every `CHAR` datatype rest all columns will be as is)

```sql
insert into SCHEMA.TARGET_TABLE_NAME 
select  
M_NB,
trim(M_INSTRUMENT),
trim(M_H_FLOWTYPE),
M_F_EXDIVD,
M_SC_FC_AC,
M_SC_FC_UC,
M_G_BRK,
M_F_LEG,
M_F_DTEEVENT,
trim(M_F_TYPELAB2),
trim(M_TYPE_UFC),
trim(M_USER_CUR),
M_REF_DATA,
M_CNT_ORG,
M_F_AMOUNT,
M_F_AMOUNTF,
trim(M_F_ANALYTIC),
trim(M_F_TYPELAB0),
trim(M_F_TYPELAB1),
trim(M_F_TYPELAB3),
trim(M_F_TYPELAB4),
M_H_F_CCNOM,
trim(M_F_TYPE),
M_F_VALUE,
M_F_REF,
trim(M_F_OBSCOM),
trim(M_ACC_CUR),
trim(M_AMD_STS),
trim(M_F_FEECOD),
trim(M_TP_CNTRP),
M_TP_DTESYS,
trim(M_TP_PFOLIO),
trim(M_TP_RTFV0),
M_TRN_GTYPE,
M_F_CCFRMCD1,
M_F_CCFRMCD2,
M_F_CCFXGDT0,
M_F_CCRATE,
trim(M_F_CTP),
trim(M_F_CURRENCY),
trim(M_F_DESTLB),
M_MX_REF_JOB,
M_TP_RTCCP02,
M_TP_RTCCP12
from SCHEMA.SOURCE_TABLE_NAME partition (PARTITION_NAME);
```

Comment: Refer to the [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73) chapter of the _PL/SQL Language Reference_ which is part of the Oracle database documentation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please clarify what is dynamic and what is static in this query. You explicitly list all the columns, so you should know which object has such structure and provide it in the `from` clause

Comment: i  have big partition table I want to insert partition wise all data from source table (CHAR data_type) to target table (VARCHAR2 data_type )  with trim all CHAR columns, I have tested above query works fine for manually putting all columns with trim ,I have multiple tables where i want dynamic script where i will put source and target table name and it will pick up and execute as per my request. I hope now its clear

Comment: Why can you not simply specify the partition key in the `where` clause? Also, it looks like you already know how to trim strings, so the part about trimming doesn't seem important for the question unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Find the partition names and then build the statement using string concatenation and use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```sql
DECLARE
  partition_names SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000) := 'insert into SCHEMA.TARGET_TABLE_NAME '
                      ||  'select col1, TRIM(col2), col3, TRIM(col4) '
                      ||  'from SCHEMA.SOURCE_TABLE_NAME';
BEGIN
  SELECT partition_name
  BULK COLLECT INTO partition_names
  FROM   ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS
  WHERE  table_owner = 'SCHEMA'
  AND    table_name  = 'SOURCE_TABLE_NAME'
  ORDER BY partition_position;

  FOR i IN 1 .. partition_names.COUNT LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql || ' PARTITION ("' || partition_names(i) || '")';
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks MT0 , i also want to create column list dynamically with trim(coulmn_name) where data_type is char , as i have multiple table to work on

Comment: @sam Then build the statement using the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` data dictionary table to append the columns in order and you can also check the data type from that table to see if you need to wrap it in a `TRIM` statement.

Comment: Trying to explain what i want , I appreciate you can help me with code:- I have big partition table I want to insert partition wise all data from source table (CHAR data_type) to target table (VARCHAR2 data_type ) with trim all CHAR columns, I have tested above query works fine for manually putting all columns with trim ,I have multiple tables where i want dynamic script where i will put source and target table name and it will pick up and execute as per my request. I hope now its clear,

Comment: @sam As I said before, build the statement using the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` to dynamically  fetch the columns and their data types. There are plenty of examples online and I am sure you are capable of looking them up.